# ViewPager с FragmentStatePagerAdapter не показывает фрагменты внутри

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, fragment-manager

Воспроизведение: перейти во фрагмент с данным `ViewPager`, переключиться в другой фрагмент и вернуться обратно.

Возможные решения, которые не сработали:

- передача `getChildFragmentManager()` на инициализации адаптера - уже было в коде на момент поиска решения этой проблемы;
- изменить `FragmentPagerAdapter` на `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` - изначально наследовалось от него, но на всякий случай попробовал изменить на `FragmentPagerAdapter` (не помогло) [+ убирал переопределение restoreState() и saveState()]
- перенести инициализацию адаптера в `onViewCreated()`, но это работает не ка нужно (показать как было до переключения на другой основной фрагмент приложения)

Фрагмент с `ViewPager` и его адаптером:

```
class SearchFragment : AbstractRetainFragment() {
    private val searchPagerAdapter by lazy { SearchPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            search_viewpager.adapter = searchPagerAdapter
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        <...>
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(fm: FragmentManager, containerID: Int, tag: String): SearchFragment {
            val fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag) as? SearchFragment
                    ?: SearchFragment()
            fragment.containerID = containerID
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

Сам адаптер:

```
class SearchPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    private val availablePages by lazy { listOf(collectionsFragment, tracksFragment) }
    private val availablePagesTitles by lazy { listOf(COLLECTIONS_FRAGMENT_TITLE, TRACKS_FRAGMENT_TITLE) }

    private val collectionsFragment by lazy { CollectionSearchFragment.newInstance(fm, Int.MIN_VALUE, COLLECTIONS_FRAGMENT) }
    private val tracksFragment by lazy { TrackSearchFragment.newInstance(fm, Int.MIN_VALUE, TRACKS_FRAGMENT) }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment // Вызывается только на первом открытии фрагмента с ViewPager
        = (availablePages.getOrNull(position) ?: availablePages.first()) as Fragment

    override fun getCount()
        = availablePages.size

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int)
        = (availablePagesTitles.getOrNull(position) ?: availablePagesTitles.first())
            .asStringRes()

    override fun restoreState(state: Parcelable?, loader: ClassLoader?) { // Dirty hack to avoid NPE of FragmentStatePagerAdapter's method
        try {
            super.restoreState(state, loader)
        } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
            // null caught
        }
    }

    override fun saveState(): Parcelable? { // Dirty hack to avoid IllegalStateException's like "Fragment no longer exists for key f0: index 0"
        return null
    }

    fun submitQuery(query: String)
        = availablePages.forEach { (it as QueryProcessor).submitQueryForProcessing(query) }

    companion object {
        private const val COLLECTIONS_FRAGMENT = "fragment of collections"
        private const val COLLECTIONS_FRAGMENT_TITLE = R.string.tab_title_collection_search

        private const val TRACKS_FRAGMENT = "fragment of tracks"
        private const val TRACKS_FRAGMENT_TITLE = R.string.tab_title_track_search
    }

    interface QueryProcessor {
        fun submitQueryForProcessing(query: String)
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто назначайте адаптер всегда, не только если `savedInstanceState == null`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло, впрочем и необходимости в этом я не увидел, всегда адаптеры устанавливаю по подобной схеме (с RecyclerView), проблем не возникало